# Python/LXML/FindAll - Can't Print Elements as Strings (brand new to python)

Tags: python, lxml, findall

When I use "findall" in the line which also "prints", which I've noted in the code with ">>>", the objects within the list are display as XML elements.  The ".text" function does not appear to have any effect, no matter where I put it within the line.  The elements are all IPv4 or IPv6 addresses - not sure if this matters.  Most solutions are different than what I am doing, and me and my coworker as stumped.  This is literally my first Python script.

**Input Sample (shortened)**

```
<rpc-reply xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/18.2R1/junos">
    <isis-database-information xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/18.2R1/junos-routing" junos:style="extensive">
        <isis-database>
            <level>1</level>
            <isis-database-entry>

                -----OUTPUT OMITTED----

                <isis-prefix xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/18.2R1/junos-routing" junos:style="normal">
                    <protocol-name>IP</protocol-name>
                    <isis-topology-id>IPV4 Unicast</isis-topology-id>
Trying to print >>> <address-prefix>1.7.11.0/32</address-prefix>
                    <metric>16</metric>
                    <prefix-flag>Internal</prefix-flag>
                    <prefix-status>up</prefix-status>
                </isis-prefix>
                <isis-prefix xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/18.2R1/junos-routing" junos:style="normal">
                    <protocol-name>IP</protocol-name>
                    <isis-topology-id>IPV4 Unicast</isis-topology-id>
                    <address-prefix>1.11.12.0/24</address-prefix>
                    <metric>32</metric>
                    <prefix-flag>Internal</prefix-flag>
                    <prefix-status>up</prefix-status>
                </isis-prefix>
```

**Output Sample (shortened)**

```
##################################################
##################################################
LSP ID: D17-HYBC03.00-00
IP Address:     [<Element address-prefix at 0x7f4cdd4d0710>, <Element address-prefix at 0x7f4cdd4d0a70>]
IPv4 Node-SID:  None
IPv6 Node-SID:  None
First SRGB Label:       None
Last SRGB Label:        None
##################################################
##################################################
LSP ID: D18-HYBC04.00-00
IP Address:     [<Element address-prefix at 0x7f4cdd4d0710>, <Element address-prefix at 0x7f4cdd4d0998>]
IPv4 Node-SID:  2018
IPv6 Node-SID:  None
First SRGB Label:       16000
Last SRGB Label:        23999
##################################################
##################################################
LSP ID: D07-DSRJ01.00-00
IP Address:     [<Element address-prefix at 0x7f4cdd4d0a28>, <Element address-prefix at 0x7f4cdd4d0908>, <Element address-prefix at 0x7f4cdd4d0710>, <Element address-prefix at 0x7f4cdd4d09e0>]
IPv4 Node-SID:  7
IPv6 Node-SID:  1007
First SRGB Label:       16000
Last SRGB Label:        23999
##################################################
##################################################
LSP ID: D08-DSRJ02.00-00
IP Address:     [<Element address-prefix at 0x7f4cdd4d0998>, <Element address-prefix at 0x7f4cdd4d0878>, <Element address-prefix at 0x7f4cdd4d0908>, <Element address-prefix at 0x7f4cdd4d0638>]
IPv4 Node-SID:  8
IPv6 Node-SID:  1008
First SRGB Label:       16000
Last SRGB Label:        23999
```

**Code**

```
from jnpr.junos import Device
from lxml import etree

####################
###etree.dump(DB)###
####################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NODE = Device(host='x.x.x.x', user='root',  password='test').open()
    DB = NODE.rpc.get_isis_database_information(level='1', extensive = True, normalize = True, )
    DB_ROOT = DB.findall('.//isis-database/isis-database-entry')

    for DB_ENTRY in DB_ROOT:

        LSPID = 'lsp-id'
        PREFIX = 'isis-prefix'
        PREFIX_ADDRESS = 'address-prefix'
        SID_V4 = 'isis-node-segment/isis-node-segment-ipv4-index'
        SID_V6 = 'isis-node-segment/isis-node-segment-ipv6-index'
        LABEL_FIRST = 'isis-node-segment/isis-node-segment-block/isis-node-segment-block-first-label'
        LABEL_LAST = 'isis-node-segment/isis-node-segment-block/isis-node-segment-block-last-label'

        print('#' * 50) 
        print('#' * 50)
        print("LSP ID:\t{LSPID}".format(LSPID=DB_ENTRY.findtext(LSPID)))
    >>> print("IP Address:\t{PREFIX_ADDRESS}".format(PREFIX_ADDRESS=DB_ENTRY.findall("isis-prefix/[metric='0']address-prefix")))    
        print("IPv4 Node-SID:\t{SID_V4}".format(SID_V4=DB_ENTRY.findtext(SID_V4)))  
        print("IPv6 Node-SID:\t{SID_V6}".format(SID_V6=DB_ENTRY.findtext(SID_V6)))      
        print("First SRGB Label:\t{LABEL_FIRST}".format(LABEL_FIRST=DB_ENTRY.findtext(LABEL_FIRST)))        
        print("Last SRGB Label:\t{LABEL_LAST}".format(LABEL_LAST=DB_ENTRY.findtext(LABEL_LAST)))
```

Comment: Note you exposed a root password in this source code which I hope you will now change if it is protecting anything important.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could trim the question down to a [mcve]. It is currently not possible for us to simply copy, paste and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

If `DB_ENTRY` is the `<isis-database-entry>` node, then `DB_ENTRY.findall("isis-prefix/address-prefix")` would be expected to find a list of all the (2) `<address-prefix>` tags.

And yes, that is what is shown in the output sample: `IP Address:     [<Element address-prefix at 0x7f4cdd4d0710>,...]`

It seems like you really want two loops, something like this:

```
for DB_ENTRY in list(DB_ROOT):
    for ISIS_PREFIX in DB_ENTRY:
        print("IP Address:\t{PREFIX_ADDRESS}".format(PREFIX_ADDRESS=ISIS_PREFIX.findall("address-prefix")[0].text))
```

Instead of `DB_ENTRY.findall()`, that has been changed to `ISIS_PREFIX.findall()`. And that `.findall()` returns a list of one, so I added `[0]` to the end to get the IP address node out of the list, then added `.text` to return the actual IP address instead of the XML node info.

My testing showed this output:

```
IP Address: 1.7.11.0/32
IP Address: 1.11.12.0/24
```